# quotient ideal & primary decomposition

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

A 'quotient ideal' associated to a pair of ideals $\frak{a}, \frak{b} $ $\subset R$ of a commutative ring with $1_R$ is a new ideal defined as $(\frak{a}:\frak{b})$ $=  \{r \in R \mid  r\frak{b} \subset \frak{a} \} $. at [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient) about quotient ideals I found a remark that needs clarification.  the assertion is that *the ideal quotient is useful for calculating primary decompositions*.

How concretly the ideal quotient helps to determine a primary decomposition of a ideal? let me remind that a primary decomposition of a ideal $\frak{a}$ is if we can write this ideal as an intersection $\frak{a}= P_1 \cap P_2 \cap ... \cap P_m$ where $\frak{P}_i$ are primary ideals. I would be very grateful if somebody could explain the main idea why the quotient ideals provide a useful tool to calculate such primary decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such example is Atiyah-Macdonald Theorem 4.5. If we assume that the decomposition is minimal, then the prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i = r(\mathfrak{P}_i)$ are precisely the ideals $r(\mathfrak{a} : x)$ for $x \in R$.

Other applications appear in Chapter 4 of Atiyah-Macdonald.