# Running a minimal primes decomposition in Macaulay2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, primary-decomposition, macaulay2

I want to compute the minimal primes decomposition of a very complicated ideal using Macaulay2. My computer's 16gb of RAM isn't enough to run the code without crashing, but I already know 46 of the primary ideals that will make up the decomposition (there should be only a few  more besides those 46). Is there any way for me to pass this information to M2 to reduce the complexity of the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I believe there is a way to do it using [colon ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient), but I'll have to think about exactly how it works. In the meantime, here's a [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727003/quotient-ideal-primary-decomposition).